# How to keep the chosen value in a combobox after redirecting to page with that value ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I saw similar questions but none with a proper answer. I have a page with a combobox that's getting it's values from a list from a database. [Here are the items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGWmW.jpg). My issue is that when I choose for example ID 2, I want to have that value chosen in the combobox after the refresh.

[Here is how it is right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGE71.jpg) (you can see from the URL that I chose the value 2 but the combobox shows 1).
Here is my code:

View:

```
        <div class="content4 flex-content4">
                        <div class="flex-item flex-item1"> 
                <input type="hidden" value="" asp-for=tournamentID id="index" />
                                    <label asp-for="tournamentID" value="Groups"></label>
                               <select id="tournament" onchange="PassSelectedValue2(this)" name="tournament" asp-for="@Model">
                    @if (Model.groups != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var number in Model.groups)
                        {
                            <option value="@number">@number</option>
                        }

                        <option value="">Knockout Stage</option>
                    }
                    </select></div>
                     <div class="flex-item flex-item2"> 
                        <table class="Leaderboard">
                            <tr>
                            <th class="id">#</th>
                            <th class="name" width="210px">Name</th>
                            <th class="matchesPlayed">Matches played</th>
                            <th class="pointsWon" width="100px">Points won</th>
                            </tr>
                            @foreach (var p in @Model.playerInThatGroup)
                            {
    
                              <tr>
                                <td class="tdleft">@p.id</td>
                                <td class="tdleft">@p.name</td>
                                <td class="tdleft">@p.listOfGames.Count</td>
                                <td class="tdleft">@p.nrOfWins</td>
                             </tr>
                            }
                         </table>
                     </div>
```

JS:

```
function PassSelectedValue2(selectObject) {
    console.log(selectObject.value);  //For testing the selected item
    window.location.href = "?group=" + selectObject.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your  description, I suggest you could try to use Jquery to achieve your requirement, you could firstly get the group id and then set it when the page loading.

More details, you could refer to below example:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
            function getUrlVars()
            {
                var vars = [], hash;
                var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
                for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
                {
                    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                    vars.push(hash[0]);
                    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                }
                return vars;
            }
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var me = getUrlVars()["group"];
        $('#tournament').val(me);
        
        });
</script>
}
```

Result:

[image]